# JavaScript- won't scroll to bottom of page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

This code is trying to scroll to the bottom of the page. But for some reason it won't work (Link has a `?wall=1` inside)

```
<!--load to bottom if posting on wall-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
 var wall=<?php echo $_GET['wall'];?>;
 if (wall===1) {
   window.scroll(0,document.body.scrollHeight)
 }
</script>
```

Please help as soon as possible!

Comment: it seems in your code _if (wall===1)_ is being fail

Comment: I tried removing the if, no dice.

Comment: you have just missed ; colon

Comment: I get an error from inputting the semicolon.

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: `alert(document.body.scrollHeight)` - what value do you get?

Answer (score 1):

Use quotes to use php code inside php code .Also == is use for equality of any type and === is eqality of same type, So use according to it.

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <html>
    some text
    </html>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     var wall = "<?php echo $wall = isset($_GET['wall']) ? $_GET['wall'] : '';  ?>";
     if (wall === "1") { //use == for different type and === for same type.
       window.scroll(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
     }
    </script>
```

Comment: I don't recommend `==` over `===` just because you using the wrong constant. I recommend using `wall === '1'` instead.

Answer (score 0):

<del>`window.scroll()` is not available in browsers yet
read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll</del>

<del>Use `window.scrollTo()`</del>

You should also wait till the document is ready with loading and additionally also until angular is done with its template processing, because this changes the `document.body.scrollHeight` value.

Additionally, if there is no GET variable you might run into an error as well

Consider changing it to this

```
var wall="<?php echo isset($_GET['wall']) ? $_GET['wall'] : 0;?>";
```

Or if you use PHP7:

```
var wall="<?=$_GET['wall'] ?? 0;?>";//also added quotes
```

Comment: That is not completely true. Window.scroll works just fine. Look at this documentation: https://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Comment: That is `jQuery`. Which means that `$(window).scroll()` works

Comment: Here look at an example where window.scroll just works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/ae927a9L/1/

Comment: Woops. Apparently `scroll` is just an alias for `scrollTo`. Sorry about that, learn something new every day

Comment: Updated my answer, I still believe the second part is relevant :)

Comment: Now when I try the function $(document).ready(function(){, it givesthis error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" Anything on this?

Comment: Did you add `jQuery` before you try to execute that function?

Comment: yup! That part is relevant ;)

Comment: I loaded the default google jquery, <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>

Comment: If you want to use `$(document).ready` you should add the full `jQuery` library. But why are you playing outside the angular framework? You should handle things like this in your app.

Comment: That's not jQuery. AngularJS includes jqlite, which contains a subset of jQuery, but I'm not sure it can be used independently of Angular.  jQuery is at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js